# How to simulate query to webpage for console?

Tags: http

I would like get data from this webpage through a terminal, the page is http://dondevoto.apps.cl/. Now I want to simulate query for console and save data in text.
I'm interesting get the city.

Any idea ?.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP, jQuery, Rails, *and* Ruby?

Comment: is curl http://dondevoto.apps.cl/ what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the data directly using a simple get request to the following:

http://hackshackers.cl/fono/servel.php?callback=?&rut=insert_here

Replace [insert_here] with the rut. It appears it will return JSON. You can use Wget or Curl to save the result.

Note: I pulled this from http://dondevoto.apps.cl/js/app.js, which shows how the website actually works.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tratare de hacer algo para la tarde.